# Nuxeo CMF interface customization

Tags: jsp, interface, customization, case, nuxeo

I tried to customize the style of `Nuxeo CMF interface` and first I edited the `D:\Nuxeo_CMF_installation\nxserver\nuxeo.war\login.jsp` file (installation done in D: drive) and updated. The changes were shown to me that time.

But when I restarted the server, the changes I made was not there. Please let me know where I Need to update to make permanent changes to the interface and also I need to know about the location where the source files of inner pages of nuxeo CMF reside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see the changes you have done on nuxeo.war after a restart because nuxeo.war is generated at the server startup. The war is generated using all the jar files in nxserver/bundles or nxserver/plugins . We did it this way to allow developers to change the application without having to fork. So the idea is to create your own jar and add it to  nxserver/plugins . If you are using eclipse you should try [Nuxeo IDE](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/ZYKE).

Comment: Hi,
   After logging in to the Nuxeo CMF interface, when I clicked the Home>>Dashboard link, it has shown an error message like "An error occurred while loading the layout". The local-host port-id is 9090. Can you please tell me the reason for this?

Thanks in Advance